# Is it possible that shell file permission got changed without user actually changing it?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, cron

I had a cron job with an executable permission till yesterday. But, for some reason today I got the crontab email alert that this particular cron job failed to execute as cron do not have permission to run this shell file.

So, I checked the shell file permission and noticed that executable permission is gone.

Not sure what could possibly changed this file permission.
Any hints will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: was the shell file at any time removed and added again? E.g. I do that using a generator script writing a lot of other scripts. Than I everytime have to set the executable flag again.

Comment: @derHugo, I do update the shell file time to time  but, I don't recall removing it.

Comment: Than how are you updating it? The flag shouldn't be removed by something like `nano <file>` or `vim <file>`

Comment: I am using GUI based editor to edit the file. Even I think by simply editing the file flag shouldn't be removed. Are there any other possibilities?